# Combining similar columns and creating a new dataframe with no duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm using pandas to find the top 10 agencies the US government spent most of its 2016 budget on. However, I'm having trouble with combining all the agencies with the same name, and adding their costs. Any help would be appreciated!

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2inGv.jpg ""

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with ideally data from your input dataframe, your code and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If we imagine that your actual data consists of two columns `Agency` and `Cost` you can use:

```
df.groupby('Agency', as_index=False)['Cost'].sum()
```

Columns in your example seem to be `Agency Name` and `2016` so:

```
df.groupby('Agency Name', as_index=False)['2016'].sum()
```

And if your dataframe is called `relevant_data`:

```
relevant_data.groupby('Agency Name', as_index=False)['2016'].sum()
```